# Hurst PAS, PBS Geared DC Step Motor

Tags: wiring, stepper-motor

I am currently trying to determine whether a Hurst PAS, PBS Geared DC stepper motor is functioning correctly.  While researching on the Hurst website, I came across a page that provides information about this specific type of stepper motor and even includes a wiring diagram.   However, the diagram has raised some doubts for me. It seems that each winding is activated using a transistor. I'm unsure whether this transistor is already integrated within the motor itself, as I have not encountered a stepper motor with this configuration before.

Unfortunately, the Hurst website lacks sufficient information and their contact form seems to have an error, making it difficult for me to gather further details. Therefore, I am seeking assistance and hoping to find some answers here.

Hust website about the PAS,PBS motors
[http://www.hurst-motors.com/paspbsgeared.html](https://www.hurst-motors.com/paspbsgeared.html)

[image: wiring diagram]
Regards to all.
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

The website says that the motor has 6 wires, then lists their colours and interpretations on the diagram with the transistors. The key is to see what nodes those colour labels are located on:
[image: data page snip]
You can see the labels are before the transistors - so the transistors are not inside the motor.

This can be verified by measuring the resistance of any of the coils (say blue/white to blue) and comparing the value with the table at the bottom of the linked page

Snip from https://www.hurst-motors.com/paspbsgeared.html